# Facebook Api Public Posts

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to grab the posts from a public Facebook group using the Facebook api. I have been reading the documentation and I haven't found a way to grab that data without logging in. But using the graph explorer I do not need to log in to get the data so there must be a way.

Is there anyway to do this using the javascript Facebook api?

Comment: You are logged in when you use Graph Explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fbusername/posts?fields=full_picture,message,created_time&date_format=F/d/Y&limit=10&access_token=useapptoken
```

you can use App token instead user access token.